# How to change the extracted protos location in gradle while using plugin gradle-plugin-protobuf-0.9.1?

Tags: gradle, protocol-buffers

While building using gradle, the protos are generated inside  my build folder and `generateProto` task looks for protos in src folder. Hence `generateProto` cannot find the protos to generate classes.

```
Error :

:generateProto
file or directory '*****/src/main/proto', not found
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: There are 3 different protobuf plugins, which one do you mean?

Comment: ws.antonov.gradle.plugins', name: 'gradle-plugin-protobuf', version: '0.9.1'

Comment: There are two properties that can be useful `extractedProtosDir` and `generatedFileDir`. Have you tried to use them?

Comment: Yes .... its generating the protos and classes in extracted-protos and  generated-sources but on task compileJava , I am getting an error as "Builder is not abstract and does not override abstract method internalGetFieldAccessorTable() in com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessage.Builder
  public static final class Builder extends"

Comment: Sorry then, I'm not able to help you.